# Vagrant: I need a provisioning system with no dependecies

Tags: puppet, chef, vagrant, ansible

Getting off the ground with a vagrant config. Host is Windows. I have a really simple config, so I wanted to use Ansible, but got this:

```
[default] Running provisioner: ansible...
The executable 'ansible-playbook' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the %PATH% variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.
```

So basically, I take this to mean Vagrant wants Ansible installed on its own, and is trying to use an existing instance of Ansible (which I do not have).

My question is: Is either Chef or Puppet **built into** Vagrant? I want to be able to just install Vagrant and run `vagrant up`, the way it's supposed to work, without having to install a provisioning system on the host apart from that.

Thank you!

Comment: If your concern with external dependencies is the difficulty in managing those dependencies, you might look into [Bindler](https://github.com/fgrehm/bindler), which can automatically install plugins for you with a `vagrant plugin bundle` command, similar to Bundler for Ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The providers that Vagrant supports require that the box used also has the correct tools already installed.  To use puppet or puppet-agent, the box you use must include puppet.  The same goes for chef and chef-solo.

Comment: So just to confirm, my only zero-dependency option is using shell scripts?

Comment: Yes from the perspective that all boxes should support the shell provider with no additional software required.  That said, there are many base boxes freely available that have puppet, and/or chef already installed.  See http://www.vagrantbox.es/ for a some freely available base boxes.

Comment: My problem is not the basebox, but the host. If i get a basebox that has puppet or chef installed, will I not need anything on the host other than Vagrant itself?

Comment: Right. The provider must be installed on the VM, not the host. I assume you got your original error because Ansible wasn't installed properly on the VM.

Comment: @sciurus Ansible runs on the host, not the VM.

Comment: One small addition: it is possible to use multiple provisioners in a Vagrantfile, e.g. you could use a shell script to install chef-client and then use chef-client as a second provisioner. -- On the other hand building a base box is really simple.

Comment: I stand corrected.  You only need to install ansible on the host, then each time it runs it copies itself onto the guests.